# ValueError: Unable to parse string "2.90 3.50 2.35" at position 0 (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to convert data in column '1x2' of the 'odds_df as below to float dtype.

I've hit a dead end so far as nothing seem to work..as far I've researched and tried.

Please I need help to overcome this and would be glad I asked :)

ps! I overlooked the code snippet in my earlier post, hopefully I got it right this time.

enter code here

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import numpy as np

odds_df = pd.read_csv('betodds.csv')

odds_df.head()

    Teams                               1x2
0   Leicester City\nManchester United   2.90\n3.50\n2.35
1   Aston Villa\nCrystal Palace         1.90\n3.70\n3.80
2   Fulham FC\nSouthampton FC           3.00\n3.40\n2.30
3   Arsenal FC\nChelsea FC              3.80\n3.70\n1.90
4   Manchester City\nNewcastle United   1.10\n9.50\n22.00

odds_df['1x2'] = odds_df['1x2'].replace('\n','  ', regex=True).values.tolist()

odds_df['1x2'] 
0      2.90  3.50  2.35
1      1.90  3.70  3.80
2      3.00  3.40  2.30
3      3.80  3.70  1.90
4     1.10  9.50  22.00
5      4.40  3.80  1.75
6      1.70  4.00  4.50
7      2.30  3.30  3.10
------------------------
Name: 1x2, dtype: object

odds_df['1x2'] = pd.to_numeric(odds_df['1x2'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "2.90  3.50  2.35"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-20aa27752bb5> in <module>
----> 1 odds_df['1x2'] = pd.to_numeric(odds_df['1x2'])

D:\Anaconda\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py in to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
    150         coerce_numeric = errors not in ("ignore", "raise")
    151         try:
--> 152             values = lib.maybe_convert_numeric(
    153                 values, set(), coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric
    154             )

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "2.90  3.50  2.35" at position 0
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @David Erickson desired output is to change the column '1x2' to float so that I can manipulate it down the code. Like doing maths computational stuff eg. divide. Thanks

Comment: see my answer. You have three different values on one column. To make the column a float column you need to have one value in the column, which is why I separated into 3. IS your ultimate goal to divide the three numbers? Or multiply? What exact calculation are you attempting?

Comment: @David Erickson. I've also tried .astype(float) and it gets me ValueError as well

Comment: @David Eickson. I would need to divide each individual value in the row into a figure of 1 for example. That means keeping them in single row format is ideal unless it's a complete no. Hope that's sounds you can follow.

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: @David Erickson Hi, I've a follow up question on the link if you get time.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65443467/11496486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: You may need to replace `\\\\` with `\\`. The way I read the data from `pd.read_clipboard()` made me have to use `\\\\`. For OP, OP used `\\`:

Your column is still a string separated by spaces. You cannot make "2.90  3.50  2.35" a number as your error indicates. You can separate the three numbers into 3 new columns and convert to `float` with `.str.split('\\\\n', expand=True).astype(float)`. Note, you need to escape the `\n` regex, but `\\n` was not working for splitting but `\\\\n` did work. There are two slashes if you do `df.to_dict()`, so you nee dto escape both of those two more times, which is why you have `\\\\`:

```
odds_df[['1x2_a', '1x2_b', '1x2_c']] = odds_df['1x2'].str.split('\\\\n', expand=True).astype(float)


Out[1]: 
                               Teams                1x2  1x2_a  1x2_b  1x2_c
0  Leicester City\nManchester United   2.90\n3.50\n2.35    2.9    3.5   2.35
1        Aston Villa\nCrystal Palace   1.90\n3.70\n3.80    1.9    3.7    3.8
2          Fulham FC\nSouthampton FC   3.00\n3.40\n2.30    3.0    3.4    2.3
3             Arsenal FC\nChelsea FC   3.80\n3.70\n1.90    3.8    3.7    1.9
4  Manchester City\nNewcastle United  1.10\n9.50\n22.00    1.1    9.5   22.0
```

From there, you can divide each column by eachother:

```
s = odds_df['1x2'].str.split('\\\\n', expand=True).astype(float)
odds_df['1x2'] = s[0] / s[1] / s[2]
odds_df
Out[1]: 
                               Teams                  1x2
0  Leicester City\nManchester United  0.35258358662613976
1        Aston Villa\nCrystal Palace  0.13513513513513514
2          Fulham FC\nSouthampton FC   0.3836317135549872
3             Arsenal FC\nChelsea FC   0.5405405405405406
4  Manchester City\nNewcastle United 0.005263157894736843
```

Comment: Your suggested solution absolutely works. Thanks